# Deleted Ubuntu partition accidentally, Grub Rescue problem

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

I have a laptop with dual os windows 7 and ubuntu 13.03.

I wanted to uninstall ubuntu from it. So, I formatted partitions of ubuntu from windows Disk management and make that free space into a new volume.

After that I restarted my system, then it shows "error: no such partition.grub rescue>"
Then I came to know that I need to reset MBR.

I tried everything like boot-repair tool, boot from windows 7 live-usb but it shows 'boot error' everytime. I need my windows back. please help me.

Thanks in advance for your kind assistance.

Comment: Sorry but we only deal with Ubuntu related problems. Yours is with Windows and it not booting. Answer will be within windows (maybe a windows resque dvd).  Something like fixmbr.

Comment: Okay, then what is the problem with boot-repair tool?

Comment: @Rinzwind Seems like you didn't understand his question. He's trying to install Ubuntu.

Comment: "I wanted to uninstall ubuntu from it"

Comment: fix windows mbr and using a windows disc (fixmbr fixboot)...
still the question itself is a windows related and doesn't belong here...

Comment: @EduardoCola no he removed ubuntu but the system still boots to grub, It is a windows problem. fixmbr.  SaishivaGudla "boot-repair" is to fix Ubuntu boot.

Comment: I'm voting this as **off-topic** here because this is a windows-related post, and off topic from here.

Comment: You can move this post to the Super User forurms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to boot from an Ubuntu live cd/usb to fix that problem. You want to boot from the live USB (try Ubuntu without installing) and reinstall GRUB in the MBR. Some relevant instructions are [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd).

As a general rule: Use Windows tool to fix windows issues and Linux tools to fix linux issues. That will save you a lot of problems in the future.

P.S. Even though this approach should fix your problem I may have missed some important details, so do some research (and backup) before trying those things.

Comment: I don't have a ubuntu live cd/usb.

Comment: Ask a friend to create one for you - it can be done from Windows as well. All you need is a 4gb usb drive.

Comment: Ok, then.. I didn't have any ubuntu partition.. I make all of them to a new volume before restarting it to do so